# Prefixos em Sentença SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-select

No SQL Server o mesmo aceita só 4 prefixos nas sentenças, ex: `Select * from pmv.banco.dbo.tabela`. No caso, estou utilizando um linked server do cliente.

Porém, quando faço referencia com algum campo da tabela, onde ficaria 5 prefixo (`pmv.banco.dbo.tabela.campo`), não consigo continuar pois o SQL não aceita. Saberiam uma possível solução pra isso ? Poderiam me dar dicas ?

```
UPDATE LINK.base.dbo.Tabela  
   SET cliq.situacao = 'C'  
  FROM LINK.base.dbo.Tabela cliq
  JOIN #tmpTabela tmp ON tmp.idreferencia = cliq.idreferencia 
  JOIN BRMLiquidacoes anu ON anu.idbrmliquidacao = tmp.IdReferencia  
  JOIN BRMLiquidacoes mov ON mov.tipomov = 1 
   AND mov.unges = anu.unges 
   AND mov.brmano = anu.brmano 
   AND mov.brmnum = anu.brmnum 
   AND mov.anoint = anu.anoint 
   AND mov.numint = anu.numint 
   AND mov.empenho = anu.empenho 
   AND mov.anoemp  = anu.anoemp  
   AND mov.valor = ABS(anu.valor)  
  JOIN LINK.base.dbo.Tabela cp ON cp.IdReferencia = mov.idbrmliquidacao  
                                          AND cp.lancto_liquidacao_cp = 'N'  
                                          AND cp.situacao = 'A'  
                                          AND cp.IdReferencia = (  
SELECT MIN(smov.idbrmliquidacao) FROM BRMLiquidacoes smov   
  JOIN LINK.base.dbo.Tabela cp ON cp.IdReferencia = smov.idbrmliquidacao  
  AND cp.lancto_liquidacao_cp = 'N'  
  AND cp.situacao = 'A'  
  WHERE smov.tipomov = 1 AND smov.unges = anu.unges AND smov.brmano = anu.brmano AND smov.brmnum = anu.brmnum AND smov.anoint = anu.anoint AND smov.numint = anu.numint AND smov.empenho = anu.empenho AND smov.anoemp  = anu.anoemp  
  AND smov.valor = ABS(anu.valor)  
                                          )  
 WHERE tmp.excluir = 1 AND tmp.data_inclusao_brm IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Atualizei minha resposta conforme seu update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É só utilizar um `alias` pra cada tabela, exemplo:

```
SELECT tabela1.campo FROM pmv.banco.dbo.tabela AS tabela1
```

E no `update`:

```
UPDATE tabela1
SET tabela1.campo2 = 'teste2'
FROM pmv.banco.dbo.tabela tabela1
WHERE tabela1.campo1 = 1;
```

#### UPDATE

Está errado o nome no seu update, de:

```
UPDATE LINK.base.dbo.Tabela  
   SET cliq.situacao = 'C'  
  FROM LINK.base.dbo.Tabela cliq
```

Para:

```
UPDATE cliq /* <-- aqui */
   SET cliq.situacao = 'C'  
  FROM LINK.base.dbo.Tabela cliq
```

Comment: Certo. So que por exemplo, estou fazendo um UPDATE onde utilizo uma temporaria com informações. Acabei adaptando e ficou assim. Ex: UPDATE tabelas.campo = 1 FROM pmv.banco.dbo.tabela tabelas join #tmporario tmp ON tmp.campo = tabelas.campo .. Porem, o SQL acasou um erro de Ambiguos.

Comment: @SebastiãoHenrique Sua mensagem saiu cortada, mas vou atualizar a resposta

Comment: Certo fiz isso no UPDATE, mas do modo como Expliquei no comentário acima, ele apresenta erro de Ambiguos. Desde já agradeço.

Comment: @SebastiãoHenrique Mostre como você está fazendo e qual coluna está dando ambigua?

Comment: UPDATE PMV.BANCO.DBO.TABELA -- Erro ocorre nesta primeira Linha, apresentando PMV.BANCO.DBO.TABELA Ambiguos 
 SET tabela.campo = tmp.campo
FROM PMV.BANCO.DBO.TABELA tabela
JOIN #temporaria tmp ON tmp.id = tabela.id

Comment: Onde tu colocou `alias`? Você não parece ter usado minha solução @SebastiãoHenrique

Comment: @SebastiãoHenrique Edita sua pergunta com o código completo que você está tentando

Comment: Obrigado cara, deu certo!!